# Rails rollback DB and revert select commits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, rollback, git-revert

We have a feature (that contained some DB migrations and 50+ changed files) that was merged into master a few commits ago. The powers that be now want that whole feature removed.

There have been **no new migrations since this feature was added** though there have been some new commits that we want to keep.

What's the best way to unwind this quickly, assuming small team and OK to force push to origin? Is it possible (read: recommended?) to:

1. rollback the migrations to the point right before this feature (PR) was merged
2. revert the git commits back to the same point
3. replay the more recent commits (by hash?) we want to keep (unrelated to the unwanted feature) back on the codebase

This will wreak havoc with other developers but we're a very small team at the moment and working together on this.

Or maybe there is a better way?

I realize rollbacks & reverts are covered in other topics here, and I've read many of them, but our situation is somewhat different as we want to rollback, revert and then replay certain commits and then bring origin up to date so it appears as though that bad feature never happened (or if easier, a merge commit reverting that feature PR would be acceptable).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So rolling back the code itself is easy and you're worried about how to deal with "some DB migrations"? How many is "some"?

Comment: @muistooshort - 6 migrations. not 'many'. Using the 'automated' `revert` functionality of Github won't work because there are apparently conflicts and Github can't/won't help with those. I'd like to keep this code in the repo if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add single migration that has code to revert all those 6 obsolete + 1 revert feature merge.

This way you'll

- still have it in git history in case there'll be need to reapply, or reuse part of functionality
- won't need to be too smart to safely reset git and DB to some state on each dev env + staging/production - which will avoid human mistakes

Comment: Is there an easy way to generate reverts for those files (many of them could be automatic, some will need conflict resolution) that I could use the output of as part of a larger commit? I suppose `revert -n hashC^..hashG` might be a start though I don't have much experience with `revert`.